# Have an unofficial job offer from the company I want to work with but is it okay to say no to the other company?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer

I believe my situation might be different. I got two offers from company A & B. Both companies have been quite keen to hire me.

Company B told me that they want to finalize everything by this week and need an answer from me so that they could start work from next week. But I told them I am being considered at company A as well & I want to see their response as well.

Here's what is different about both opportunities, B is a **contract** position which would be less than a year & A is a **full time** position with perks. And my preference is with A since I have interned with them in the past and they know me well. I contacted company A too, they say that **do** have an offer to extend to me and have most of the approvals but some still are left, basically they extended me an unofficial job offer and I accepted it.

So should I say no to company B or wait for official paperwork to confirm everything?

**Reason for my question being different**

None of them have extended me an official letter of job offer yet but the company A did extend me an unofficial job offer and is waiting for some approvals to finish.

Comment: I did this once.  The 'unofficial' offer ended up not coming through.  So I went from two offers to zero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On unofficial job offer has no value. If they run into a snag the written offer may never materialize.

You have to decide when you can no longer wait for that final offer and make a decision. If you tell company B no and A goes silent, you will not have a job with either company.

Keep looking until you have a written offer in hand and have returned it.

If Company B doesn't meet your needs, and you can afford to turn it down, then you have your answer. If it does meet your needs or you desperately need the money; then if A won't commit pick company B.

Comment: You're right. One more thing, they (company A) actually explicitly asked me what they can offer to keep me.

Comment: which company: A or B?

Comment: It's the company A.

Comment: You can point out to company A your predicament. Say that you don't want to go but without something in writing you may have no choice. They should be able to speed things up a little. Especially as you seem to be on good terms with them.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise not turning down an offer from a company or notifying an employer of change in employment until an offer letter has been sent, signed and the return confirmed.

Between an "unoffical" offer and time of receipt things can happen.  Whether this be hiring freeze, pay freeze, etc you never know.